# Can a record with a string field accept a null in C#?

Tags: f#

For example, if I have a record such as:

```
type sample = { userId : string; }
```

and then I define this record in C# such as:

```
var samp = new sample()
                    {
                       userId = null;
                    };
```

and then if I assign this record to an F# function called in C# what would happen? Is this legal? Would I just simply have to check for null within the F# function, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general, any reference type may be null. The F# compiler prevents null assignment to F#-specific types such as records and discriminated unions in F# code. However, it is still possible to assign null to variables of these types from C#.

String is a reference type and may be null, even from F#. Your C# code is slightly inaccurate in that the type `sample` would have `userId` in the constructor:

```
var samp = new sample(null);
```

If you annotate the `sample` type is [CLIMutable attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx) then it will also have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: So how would I perform the null check on the f# side? I tried using <> but I was getting an Infix error.

Comment: `let isNullString (s:string) = if s = null then true else false`

Comment: Personally, I'd just wrap every field that I can reasonably suspect of being `null` into `Option` on F# side. You can easily put together `Option.create` function that would wrap `null` reference into `None` and anything else into `Some`.

Comment: Why not just `let isNullString (s:string) = s = null` or even `let isNull o = o = null` (the second function works with any type that can be null; the compiler infers the constraint `when 'a : null`).  In fact, I would be unlikely to define either of these functions, just using `s = null` where a boolean value is needed and `(=) null` where a function is needed.